# Server-Side-Encryption-Customer-Key : The calculated MD5 hash of the key did not match the hash that was provided

Tags: amazon-s3, encryption

I am using Jets3t as third party. I want to set server side encryption with customer-key. I am using following code but always getting message  **"The calculated MD5 hash of the key did not match the hash that was provided."**

I am using customer key ="123456" in base64-encoded and customer-key-md5  based64-encoded(md5(customer-key))

**x-amz-copy-source​-server-side​-encryption​-customer-key**
Include this header to provide the base64-encoded encryption key for Amazon S3 to use to decrypt the source object. This encryption key must be the one that you provided Amazon S3 when you created the source object; otherwise, Amazon S3 will not be able to decrypt the object.

**x-amz-copy-source-​server-side​-encryption​-customer-key-MD5**
Include this header to provide the base64-encoded 128-bit MD5 digest of the encryption key according to RFC 1321.

**Code is here**

```
try {
    S3Copy objS3Copy = new S3Copy((S3Service)new RestS3Service(new ProviderCredentials("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx") {
        @Override
        protected String getTypeName() {
        }
        @Override
        protected String getVersionPrefix() {
        }
    }), new BucketExplorerMain());
    Map<String, Object> newMetadata = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    newMetadata.put("ETag","c2fb88d3d9832648cb0b89957479c16b");
    newMetadata.put("Content-Length","1326017");
    newMetadata.put("accept","eng");
    newMetadata.put("request-id","039A1F919BAB9D1A");
    newMetadata.put("Last-Modified","Thu Feb 13 17:50:17 IST 2014");
    newMetadata.put("Date","Tue Jul 08 17:05:10 IST 2014");
    newMetadata.put("id-2","YpdNQhxKnATh6O9Pp4b/6GbDDcIcGh+UkTMQZpOyij4oNPsdOQbLGavfDSxSiuGS");
    newMetadata.put("Content-Type","text");
    newMetadata.put("x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-algorithm","AES256");
    String sKey="123456";
    //String sEncryKey = ServiceUtils.toBase64(sKey.getBytes());
    String sEncryKey = Base64.encodeBase64String(sKey.getBytes());
    newMetadata.put("x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key",sEncryKey);
    try {
        //String sbased64MD5 = ServiceUtils.toBase64(ServiceUtils.computeMD5Hash(sKey.getBytes()));
         String sbased64MD5=Base64.encodeBase64String(ServiceUtils.computeMD5Hash(new ByteArrayInputStream(sKey.getBytes())));
        newMetadata.put("x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key-MD5",sbased64MD5);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    try {
        boolean bsuccess = objS3Copy.updateMeta("BucketName", "obj.JPG", newMetadata);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }

} catch (Exception ex) {
}
```

My Values are : for key 123456

```
x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-algorithm: AES256
x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key: MTIzNDU2
x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key-MD5:  RTEwQURDMzk0OUJBNTlBQkJFNTZFMDU3RjIwRjg4M0U=
Ref: 
http://www.base64decode.org/
http://www.convertstring.com/Hash/MD5  
E10ADC3949BA59ABBE56E057F20F883E is MD5 of 123456
 The calculated MD5 hash of the key did not match the hash that was provided.
```

After changing commented line with following line.. my code is working fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The MD5 output has length of 16 bytes, while the Base64 value `RTEwQURDMzk0OUJBNTlBQkJFNTZFMDU3RjIwRjg4M0U=` actually encodes 32 bytes. You could have found this by yourself if you would have printed the values in the same encoding instead of mixing hex and base64.

I do not know where the `ServiceUtils.computeMD5Hash()` is defined, but it returns an upper-case hex representation of the MD5 hash instead of the byte array.

`md5( "123456".getBytes() )` is `0hE10ADC3949BA59ABBE56E057F20F883E`, and `base64( "E10ADC3949BA59ABBE56E057F20F883E".getBytes() )` is `RTEwQURDMzk0OUJBNTlBQkJFNTZFMDU3RjIwRjg4M0U=`, as demonstrated by the following code:

```java
MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance( "MD5" );
String keyAsText = "123456";
byte[] keyAsBytes = keyAsText.getBytes();
byte[] digestAsBytes = md5.digest( keyAsBytes );
String digestAsHex = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary( digestAsBytes );
System.out.printf( "hex(md5(\"%s\") = %s%n", keyAsText, digestAsHex );
byte[] digestAsHexAsBytes = digestAsHex.getBytes();
String digestAsHexAsBytesAsBase64 = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary( digestAsHexAsBytes );
System.out.printf( "base64(\"%s\") = %s%n", digestAsHex, digestAsHexAsBytesAsBase64 );
```